# Java - Reference Variables

Tags: java

> " It is important to understand that
>   it is the type of reference variable -
>   not the type of object that it refers
>   to - that determines what members can
>   be accessed. "

What do you exactly mean by that statement ?
Is this restricted to concept of Inheritance ?
How does JVM handles it ?

Comment: Where is this quote taken from?

Comment: Sorry,But I don't exactly remember that...
Let me know ,if I am not allowed to ask question based on quotes posted on some websites.

Comment: BTW, the quote does not show up in a Google search ... apart for this page.  Either you mistyped it, or you got it from some website that is not indexed by Google !?!

Comment: @Stephen: or even from a *book*!

Comment: You are allowed to quote websites. But providing a quote without saying who wrote it and where you found it is sloppy, lazy or both.

Comment: @Joachim - but he implied he got it from a website ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It means that suppose you have:

```
Object x = "hello";
```

The type of the *variable* is `Object`, but the type of the object it refers to is `String`. it's the variable type which determines what you can do though - so you can't call

```
// Invalid
String y = x.toUpperCase();
```

The compiler only knows that you're calling a method on `Object`, which doesn't include `toUpperCase`. Similarly, overloaded methods are only resolved against the ones you know about:

```
public class Superclass
{
    public void foo(Object x) {}
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass
{
    public void foo(String y) {}
}
...
Subclass x = new Subclass();
Superclass y = x;

x.foo("hello"); // Calls Subclass.foo(String)
y.foo("hello"); // Calls Superclass.foo(Object)
```

Answer (score 5):

For example:

```
Bike b = new Bike();
Bike b2 = new MountainBke();
b.speedUp();
b2.speedUp();
b2.shiftGearUp();
```

In the above example, assume that a bike does not have the `shiftUp` method.  The line `b2.shiftGearUp()` would not compile because the JVM only knows that `b2` is a `Bike`, not a `MountainBike`.

You could make it work by casting it to a mountain bike type:

```
((MountainBike)b2).shiftGearUp(); // This compiles and runs propperly
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java a reference of `base` class type can refer to a object of `child` class. But using such a reference we can only access the members of the `base` class that were inherited to the `child` class and not the members that the `child` class might have added.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class `Foo` with a public field `foo` and a class `Bar extends Foo` with a public field `bar`...

- `Foo myRef = new Bar();` will only allow you to access `myRef.foo` even though the object is really a `Bar`.
- `Bar myRef = new Bar();` allows access to both `myRef.foo` and `myRef.bar`. Because the reference is declared as `Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Base
{
   public object BaseMethod()
   { 
      return new String("From Base");
   }

}

public class Child extends Base
 {
   public object BaseMethod()
   {
      return new String("From Child.BaseMethod (overridden)");
   }

   public object ChildMethod()
   {
      return new String("From Child.ChildMethod");
   }
}

public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Base base = new Child();
       System.out.println(base.BaseMethod()); //prints "From Child.BaseMethod (overridden)"

       System.out.println(base.ChildMethod()); //Will not compile as ChildMethod as reference is of type Base, and ChildMethod is not specified.

       Child child = (Child) base; //But I can cast it.
       System.out.println(child.ChildMethod()); // This will work.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "It is important to understand that it
>   is the type of reference variable -
>   not the type of object that it refers
>   to - that determines what members can
>   be accessed. "

What this means is that the compiler checks the class of the reference variable for the presence of methods and other members, for example, say that you have a `Dog` subclass which extends `Animal` baseclass,

```
Animal obj=new Dog();
obj.makeSound();
```

Here the compiler checks whether the makeSound() method is declared in the Animal class or not for it to compile.