# Superclass references to subclass objects

Tags: java, inheritance, reference, polymorphism

I am confused: I have taken the following quotes (with the titles of the sections in which they appear) from a learning resource, but the quotes seem to me to contradict each other.

#### Superclass References and Subclass Objects

"it is the type of the reference variable-not the type of the object that it refers to-that determines what members can be accessed"

#### Overridden Methods Support Polymorphism

"*it is the type of the object being referred to* (not the type of the reference variable) that determines which version of an overridden method will be executed"

Any clarification on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Curious here... Where did you get these?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Reference Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500555/java-reference-variables)

Comment: Part of your question is duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500555/java-reference-variables

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate of that question. I think it adds more to it.

Comment: @Jayan - this isn't a duplicate. Rather, this question is purely about polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have two classes.

```java
class Vehicle{
    
    public void drive(){
        System.out.println("Vehicle is Moving");
    }
}
```

```java
class Car extends Vehicle{
    
    public void drive(){
        System.out.println("Car is Moving");
    }
    
    public void playMusic(){
        System.out.println("Car is Playing Music");
    }
}
```

**"it is the type of the reference variable-not the type of the object that it refers to-that determines what members can be accessed"**

It means if we have a code like
`Vehicle vehicle = new Car();`
Using `vehicle` object, we can call `drive()`, but not `playMusic()`, Because type of `vehicle` is `Vehicle`.

**"it is the type of the object being referred to (not the type of the reference variable) that determines which version of an overridden method will be executed"**

It means if we have a code like

```java
Vehicle vehicle = new Car();
vehicle.drive();
```

It will print "Car is Moving" not "Vehicle is Moving", becasue the object stored in `vehicle` is an instance of `Car`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below program.

```
class SuperMem{
    int i = 90;
    int j = 100;

    void show(){
        System.out.println("parent show..");
        System.out.println("Show inside Parent start");
        System.out.println(i + " " + j);
        System.out.println("Show inside Parent END");
    }
}

class submem extends SuperMem{
    int i = 10;
    int j = 20;
    void show(){
        System.out.println("Child show ..");
        System.out.println("Show inside Child start");
        System.out.println(i + " " + j);
        System.out.println("Show inside Child END");

    }
}

public class SuperMemDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperMem m = new SuperMem();
        submem s = new submem();
        m = s;

        System.out.println("i " + m.i);
        System.out.println("j " + m.j);
        m.show();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
   i 90
   j 100
   Child show ..
   Show inside Child start
   10 20
   Show inside Child END
```

Methods are resolved via dynamic dispatch methods i.e. at runtime. Analyse output and you will get meaning of above two statements from Complete reference Herbert Schildt

Answer (score 0):

If classB extends ClassA and you have :

```
ClassA a = new ClassB ();
```

Using the `a` variable, you can only access members defined in `ClassA` (or super-classes of `ClassA` or interfaces that `ClassA` implements). You can't access a member defined in `ClassB` that's not defined in `ClassA` (unless you cast `a` to `ClassB`).

However, calling a method of `ClassA` that's overridden in `ClassB` will execute the `ClassB` method.

Comment: Thanks all - I have a better understanding now. Anubian Noob, the quotes are from a text book, most of which I find clear to follow.

Answer (score 0):

**Superclass References and Subclass Objects**

Assuming Child extends Parent, let's look at this:

```
Parent obj = new Child();
```

Now if we try to use `obj`, we can only use behavior (methods) specified in the Parent class. We can't use any new methods from the Child class.

However, let's say both Parent and Child have a method `public String whoAmI()`.

Parent:

```
 return "Parent";
```

Child:

```
return "Child";
```

Now if we run this code:

```
Parent obj1 = new Child();
Parent obj2 = new Parent();

System.out.println(obj1.whoAmI());
System.out.println(obj2.whoAmI());
```

Output:

```
Child
Parent
```

So you can only access methods in the class you're referring to it by (Parent in the first snippet). But if you've overriden it in the class it is instantiated as (Child in the first snippet), and override a method in the parent in the child, then invoking the method present in the parent will call the method overriden in the child.